# git cherry-pick says nothing to commit

Tags: git, github, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick, git-detached-head

(note: this is not a duplicate question, see explanation below)

I first checkout master as a detached branch:

```
% git checkout --detach master
HEAD is now at fff9e1e687 modserver/go: skip Spotlight automod aspect ratio check for cheerio vids
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

I then try to cherry pick my branch:

```
% git cherry-pick my_branch
Already up to date.
HEAD detached at refs/heads/master
You are currently cherry-picking commit 65b12d9d32.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096244/why-is-git-cherrypick-saying-nothing-to-commit) prior StackOverflow post, this suggests that the commit I'm cherry picking contains no new changes. But `git diff` says that it does:

```
% git diff 65b12d9d32
diff --git a/ranking/acumen/datawizard/BUILD b/ranking/acumen/datawizard/BUILD
deleted file mode 100644
index 1d61abec2f..0000000000
--- a/ranking/acumen/datawizard/BUILD
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,13 +0,0 @@
-load("//tools:go.bzl", "go_library")
-
-go_library(
-    name = "go_default_library",
-    srcs = [
-        "handler.go",
-    ],
-    visibility = ["//ranking/acumen:__subpackages__"],
-    deps = [
-        "//ranking/logging/log:go_default_library",
-        "@com_github_valyala_fasthttp//:go_default_library",
-    ],
-)
diff --git a/ranking/acumen/datawizard/handler.go b/ranking/acumen/datawizard/handler.go
deleted file mode 100644
index 388104cf57..0000000000
--- a/ranking/acumen/datawizard/handler.go
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,22 +0,0 @@
-package datawizard
```

Comment: "this is not a duplicate question" That's debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff 65b12d9d32` compares the tree as of commit 65b12d9d32 to your current working copy. Since your working copy is clean, it's equivalent to `git diff HEAD 65b12d9d32`

On the other hand, `git cherry-pick 65b12d9d32` calculates the difference between commit 65b12d9d32 and its parent - the changes "introduced by" commit 65b12d9d32.

You can view that with `git show 65b12d9d32`, or `git diff 65b12d9d32^ 65b12d9d32` (`^` meaning "first parent of").

From there, it is probably the same scenario as the question you linked: [Why is git-cherrypick saying nothing to commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096244/why-is-git-cherrypick-saying-nothing-to-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Stash all your current changes using `git stash`.

Then run `git cherry-pick -n {comitId}`. If there are any differences between your branch and the {commitId} then it will be staged to your current branch.

Using `-n` with cherry-pick does not make a commit to you branch. It only stages the changes, if there are any.

You can check those differences now using `git diff`.

If it shows that there are no changes then it means that code from {commitId} is already in your current branch.

If it shows any changes then you can commit them using `git commit -m {message}`